# Entity Framework - mapping one class to two tables with many to one relation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a class which represent a connection of a page and a tag and it looks more or less like this:

```
public class TagLink {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PageId { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

In my database I would like to have 2 tables: `TagLinks` and `TagNames`. First one with `Id`, `PageId` and `TagId` and the second one with `TagId` and `TagName`.

I would like the tag id to be a foreign key so many tag links can be assigned to a single tag name.

I gave it a try with `EntityTypeConfiguration` but I don't know how to configure it properly. It gives me wrong foreign keys which are built like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TagNames]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TagNames_dbo.TagLinks_TagId] FOREIGN KEY([TagId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[TagLinks] ([TagId]);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TagNames] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TagNames_dbo.TagLinks_TagId]
```

I started off with this:

```
public class TagLinkEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TagLink>
{
    public TagLinkEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(e => e.Id);
        HasKey(e => e.TagId);

        Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName(nameof(TagLink.Id));
        Property(e => e.PageId).HasColumnName(nameof(TagLink.PageId));           
        Property(e => e.TagId).HasColumnName(nameof(TagLink.TagId));
        Property(e => e.TagName).HasColumnName(nameof(TagLink.TagName));

        Map(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(e => new
            {
                e.Id,
                e.PageId,                    
                e.TagId
            });
            m.ToTable("TagLinks");
        });

        Map(m =>
        {
            m.Properties(e => new
            {
                e.TagId,
                e.TagName
            });
            m.ToTable("TagNames");
        });
    }
}
```

How do I make it work with many to one relation? I guess the foreign key should be added on `TagLinks` table to reference `TagId` in `TagNames` table

Comment: @mjwills I edited my question and posted what is generated in the database

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
public class TagLink {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int PageId { get; set; }

    public int TagId { get; set; }

    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class Tag {
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TagLink> TagLinks { get; set; }
}
```

Skip the `TagLinkEntityConfiguration` definitions and let EF's code-first conventions to take over and solve the problem for you.

Comment: Sure, I know about this solution but that's what I wanted to avoid. I would like to stick to one class only. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Could have made that more clear in your question.  AFAIK there's no way to make a many to one relationship in EF without using multiple classes.

Comment: You can do it with a one-to-one relationship using table splitting, or with a many-to-one relationship with duplicate TagName values, but a single class will not support a normalized many-to-one relationship in EF.